# Functions high school olympiad level.

Tags: functions

Show that there exist functions $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto\mathbb{R}\;$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}\;$ such that $f(g)=g(f)\;$ and $f(f)=g(g)\;$ and $f(x) \neq g(x)\;$ for all real $x$$\\$
$\\$
$\\$b) Prove that if $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto\mathbb{R}\;$ and $g: \mathbb{R} \mapsto\mathbb{R}\;$   are continuous and have the properties $f(g)=g(f)\;$ and $f(x) \neq g(x)\;$ for all real $x$ then $(f(f))(x) \neq(g(g))(x)\quad$ for all real $x$

Hi. Im a high schooler who trying this question. I havent the slightest idea how to proceed and would like if someone could help me through this.

Comment: Hello! Generally, `\Re` is reserved for the function that returns the real part of a complex number. For the set of all real numbers, use `\Bbb{R}`.

Comment: First, when it says `show that there exists` they mean, find two specific examples of functions that satisfy the following constraints.
Next, can you find two functions that satisfy `f(x) \neq g(x)`? what about `f(g) = g(f)` or `f(f) = g(g)`?

Comment: x and -x seem.to do.that

Comment: Those functions have the same value at 0

Comment: I see. How to find such functions then?

Comment: I have fixed my answer for the first part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no general method, except imagination which comes with experience, I'm afraid.

Here is how I found an example: the relation $f(g)=g(f)$ reminded me of the characterisation  of odd/even functions: an $odd$ function satisfies the relation 
$$\forall x,\;f(-x)=-f(x)$$
which is the required relation for $g(x)=-x$. Now $g\bigl(g(x)\bigl)=x$, so we also must have  $f\bigl(f(x)\bigl)=x$, in other words $f$ must be its own inverse, and different  from $-x$. There aren't so many functions at an elementary level, but one obvious answer is 
$$f(x)=\frac1x.$$
Last requirement $\;f(x)\ne g(x)$ for all $x$. It's automatically satisfied since $\dfrac 1x=-x$ implies $x^2+1=0$, which have no real root.

Yet there's one flaw: $f(x)$ is not defined at $x=0$.Never mind: we'll slightly change the definition of $f$ and set
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac1x&\text{ if } x\ne 0,\\[1ex]1&\text{ if } x=0.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Great thanks for the explanation what about part b ?

Comment: Hi Bernard, I had a similar answer for the first part that I was working at the same time as you and had finished even before you had posted this answer. I had deleted that answer because it had a small flaw and then reposted a different answer that was similar to the first-- but modified so that it was correct-- I want to clarify that my answer(s) were independent of yours. If mine does not have value, I'll gladly delete. Thanks, -Russ

Comment: Don't. Your answer is fine. Our difference is that I mainly focused on how I was led to this solution (that's why I posted some 5 min after you).

Comment: anything for part b ?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, $g(x) = -f(x)$ almost work. Now define $f(0)=1$.

Note: these functions are not continuous at $0$. But continuity was not a stated requirement for the first part of the exercise.
(This makes sense, as in the second part, it is a task to prove that continuous examples $f,g$ do not exist.)